# Why is my mongoose update not finding a match?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following document in my cart collection:

```
{
"_id": {
  "$oid": "6555453298c59137f9cb2ee5"
},
"userId": {
  "$oid": "6555453298c59137f9cb2ee3"
},
"email": "aaaaaa@aaa.com",
"items": [
  {
    "quantity": 3,
    "product": {
      "$oid": "655437995bc92c0647deb512"
    },
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "65555277fe01541a2052bd5f"
    }
  },
  {
    "quantity": 1,
    "product": {
      "$oid": "655437995bc92c0647deb513"
    },
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "65555278fe01541a2052bd65"
    }
  }
}
```

In the items array, I want to increase the quantity by 1 where the product (productId) = 655437995bc92c0647deb512. My increase function is as follows:

```
exports.increaseProductQuantity = async (req, res) => {
console.log('user.service increaseProductQuantity')
const {productId} = req.body;
console.log('productIdd', productId)
const email = authenticateToken(req, res)

console.log('increaseProductQuantity email', email)
(increaseProductQuantity email logs aaaaaa@aaa.com)


try {
    await Cart.updateOne({
        "email": email
    }, {
        "$inc": {
            "items.$.quantity": 1
        }
    }, {
        "arrayFilters": [{
            "items.product": productId
        }]
    })

    const cart = await Cart.findOne({
        email: email,
    }).populate({
        path: 'items.product',
        model: 'Products'
    })

    console.log('cart', cart)

    // const newCart = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cart));
    // newCart.cartTotal = computeCartTotal(newCart);
    // console.log('newCart', newCart)

    // res.status(201).json(newCart)
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).send('Problem changing item quantity.')
}
```

}

I get the error:

```
MongoServerError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `updateOne` query to match the `productId` directly:

```
await Cart.updateOne(
  {
    "email": email,
    "items.product": productId
  },
  {
    "$inc": {
      "items.$.quantity": 1
    }
  }
);
```

Or you could use `findOneAndUpdate` with the `new` option to directly retrieve the updated `cart`:

```
const cart = await Cart.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "email": email, "items.product": productId },
  { "$inc": { "items.$.quantity": 1 } },
  { new: true, populate: { path: 'items.product', model: 'Products' } }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

@eekinci's answer is correct which it will update the **first** matching element in the `items` array via [`$`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#syntax) by assuming that the `product` value is unique.

For your current implementation with `arrayFilters`, you must apply the [filtered positional operator `$[<identifier>]`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#syntax).

```
await Cart.updateOne({
  "email": email
},
{
  "$inc": {
    "items.$[item].quantity": 1
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "item.product": productId
    }
  ]
});
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uSOT6StUb8I)